# way to train deep learning model twith npy images in one folder

Tags: python, pandas, image, numpy, deep-learning

Hi i have 100000 images stored as .npy in one folder.
Also i have another folder with .npy as labels.
Additionally i have csv file of pandas inside image name label and more stuff.
Now how i can train deep learning model since **imagedatagenerator** usually works with jpg folder configured as : train, test, validation, folders and each class has separate folder inside.
I use

```
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train_one_hot, batch_size=25, epochs=100, validation_split=0.3)
```

Comment: what deep learning framework are you using? tesnorflow or pytorch or some other? Also, post code used for loading data.

Comment: get source code of `imagedatagenerator` and create own `imagedatagenerator`

Comment: im using keras from example https://vijayabhaskar96.medium.com/tutorial-image-classification-with-keras-flow-from-directory-and-generators-95f75ebe5720   yes i can try change generators its big work or maybe write script to split images as imagegenerator expect